# Adding a "//" on the x-axis to remove whitespace in one side of the ggplot panel plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm hoping if there's a way to remove whitespace in one side of the panel plot (created by `facet_wrap`) by adding "//" on the x-axis. Below is sample data and code:

```
df <- data.frame(
  condition = c("cond1","cond2","cond3"),
  measure   = c("type1","type2"),
  value     = rep(NA, 6)
  )

# all type 1 measure values are between -0.5 and 0.5
# all type 2 measure values are between 0.5 and 2
df[df$measure=="type1",]$value <- runif(3, min=-0.5, max=0.5)
df[df$measure=="type2",]$value <- runif(3, min= 1.5, max=2.0)

# both panels should have same axis tick intervals
custom_breaks = function(x){
  seq(round(min(x), 2), round(max(x), 2), 0.2)
}

# create a panel plot with vertical line at y=0 for both panels
ggplot(df, aes(x=condition, y=value, color=measure)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0), color="grey") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=custom_breaks) +
  facet_wrap(~measure, scales="free_x") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

This code returns the below plot:

[image]

Because the values for type 2 (right panel) are far off from zero, adding a vertical line at y=0 results in lots of whitespace. I'm wondering if there's a way to put a "//" on the x-axis on the right panel after 0 and going straight to 1.5 so there aren't tons of wasted white space. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about setting `xlim`?

Comment: you can check here : https://stackoverrun.com/fr/q/12277293

Answer (score 1):

Broken axes are generally discouraged because they can lead to misleading visualizations, so this is intentionally not implemented in ggplot2 (as answered by [Hadley Wickham himself](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/jSrL_FnS8kc/MvzM_2_jiSIJ)).
My preferred solutions for something like this are (a) facetting (which you are already doing) or (b) log transormation of the axis - but only if it makes sense for the given data.

Take this barchart for example ([source](https://doi.org/10.2214/AJR.19.22176) / [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKenH.png)): Since there is valuable information in the outliers (red circle and arrows) both log transformation and broken axes would distort the representation of reality. The package `library(ggforce)` has an implementation for such zoom facets with the `facet_zoom()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scales = "free_x"` is working just fine - the issue is that your `geom_hline` putting a line at 0 is included in both facets. Here's a way to include it only on the first facet.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=condition, y=value, color=measure)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(data = data.frame(measure = "type1"), aes(yintercept=0), color="grey") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=custom_breaks) +
  facet_wrap(~measure, scales="free_x") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I'd actually like to keep vertical line at y=0 in both facets as a reference line, which is why I was hoping to insert an axis break in the second facet. it seems like the general consensus is "ggplot doesn't support this" though. thanks for suggesting your solution!

Comment: A reference line paired with an axis break seems contradictory to me... references lines are used to make direct comparisons clear, broken axes to indicate that a direct comparison isn't appropriate.